# Pyspark complex when statement

Tags: pyspark

I got the following when statement:

```
.withColumn('is_boost', F.when(
 ((F.col('num_clicks') < 600)
 & (F.col('num_bookings') < 2)
 & (F.col('num_impressions') < 6000))
 | (F.col('property_id').isNull())
 , 1).otherwise(0))).cache()
```

I want a situation where if num_bookings & num_clicks & num_impressions are all below the thresholds I specified for them, it the value will be '1' **OR**, if property_id is null, where I also want the value to be '1'. Otherwise I want the value to be '0'.

However, when I run this code, I get a situation where a row has num_impressions == 20,000 and I still get unexpectedly the value is_boost == 1.

Any advice on what is wrong with this statement, and how to fix it?

Comment: For that case ```num_impressions == 20,000``` is ```property_id``` null?

Comment: no, property_id is not null in that case

Comment: ```property_id```  is empty? Or is it ```None```? And these columns are of what type? Send a snapshot of the df. A ```df.printSchema()```would also be nice